# How to get updated state from Redux store using redux-toolkit after component has already rendered?

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit, thunk, getstate

The functionality I am looking for is that of an e-commerce website. A click on the add-to-cart button adds product to cart. I am able to successfully achieve that by dispatching an action.
Post that I want to grab the state of the updated cart without having to re-render the component and save it to localStorage.
Since the component does not re-render on its own, the value of cartItems fetched by useSelector on the initial render is not the updated one and hence always is one update behind.
I am relatively new to redux and completely new to redux-toolkit. With my research so far, I figured out that getState() and redux-thunk may be of help, but didn't seem to get a good code example.

**this is the cartSlice**

```
const cartSlice = createSlice({
  name: "cart",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    // Todo: add pizza to cart
    addItemToCart: (state, { payload }) => {
      const newItem = payload;
      const existingItem = state.cartItems.find(
        (item) => item.id === newItem.id && item.varient === newItem.varient
      );

      if (existingItem) {
        existingItem.quantity = existingItem.quantity + newItem.quantity;
        existingItem.price =
          existingItem.quantity * existingItem.prices[0][existingItem.varient];
      } else {
        state.cartItems.push(newItem);
      }
    },
```

**And the add to cart function**

````
  const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState(1);
  const cartItems = useSelector((state) => state.cart.cartItems);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const handleAddToCart = (pizza, varient, quantity) => {
    let item = {
      id: pizza._id,
      name: pizza.name,
      image: pizza.image,
      varient,
      quantity,
      price: pizza.prices[0][varient] * quantity,
      prices: pizza.prices,
    };
    dispatch(addItemToCart(item));
    dispatch(setTotalPrice());
    dispatch(setCartCount());

    // i want to grab the current state here after it has been updated in line 27 and save it in local storage
  };```
````

Answer (score 2):

### The problem

You do not exactly need a re-render to happen for accessing the latest state from your store. Your state is one update behind, because you're trying to fetch values from `useSelector` right after your `dispatch` calls. The `dispatch` calls are asynchronous (but there is no promise to "await" them by default), so your state is not guaranteed to be up-to-date by the time your selector call goes through.

### Solution

Move your selector call into a separate `useEffect` hook that is triggered every time `cartItems` changes.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (cartItems) {
      // Do your thing here
    }
}, [cartItems]); // Guaranteed to be triggered *after* each update
```

### Possible Alternative

I have read that you could `await` the `dispatch` calls using `createAsyncThunk`, but I have not personally tried it. Given your requirement here, though, I don't think you need to go that far. Here is the documentaion for `createAsyncThunk`, if you're interested: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk

Comment: 'The dispatch calls are asynchronous'
I believe that they're not?

Answer (score 0):

I think a good approach is to make a custom hook like this:

```
    const useSaveToLocalstorage = (trigger, data) => {
      useEffect(() => {
        if (data) window.localStorage.setItem(data.key, data.value);
      }, [trigger]);
};
```

And to call it like this *(Your code)*:

```
const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState(1);
const cartItems = useSelector((state) => state.cart.cartItems);
const dispatch = useDispatch();
useSaveToLocalStorage(state.cart.cartItems, { key: 'cart.items',
                                                  value: state.cart.cartItems });

const handleAddToCart = (pizza, varient, quantity) => {
  let item = {
    id: pizza._id,
    name: pizza.name,
    image: pizza.image,
    varient,
    quantity,
    price: pizza.prices[0][varient] * quantity,
    prices: pizza.prices,
  };
  dispatch(addItemToCart(item));
  dispatch(setTotalPrice());
  dispatch(setCartCount());

  // i want to grab the current state here after it has been updated in line 27 and save it in local storage
};
```

You can't access the updated state after a direct action dispatch, since the store update is an asynchronous task, but you can react to store slice change, by using a useEffect with that state slice as dependency.